# error: template parameter redeclared here as 'false'. some template magic

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-specialization

I try to implement kinda smart Pair class in metaprogramming technique on c++. I want my class can contain different types and constants. Like in code below:

```
template <typename F, typename S>
struct Pair {
    typedef F first;
    typedef S second;
};

template <typename F, bool Cond>
struct Pair {
    typedef F first;
    static const bool second = Cond;
};
```

But this code leads to compilation error on gcc 4.8.1

```
error: template parameter ‘class S’
template <typename F, typename S>
                      ^
error: redeclared here as ‘bool Cond’
```

Is there some way to overload a structure by const template parameter?

Comment: You can't "overload" templates on template parameters. Also your specialization is pretty pointless, you could just do `static const bool second = Cond` and not have to specialize.

Comment: yes, it's true. This can be done without specializing, but i still wonder, why i can't overload template to have different instances for types and integral values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this suit your needs?

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename F, typename S>
struct Pair {
    typedef F first;
    typedef S second;
};

template <typename F>
struct Pair<F, std::integral_constant<bool, true>> {
    typedef F first;
    static const bool second = false;
};

template <typename F>
struct Pair<F, std::integral_constant<bool, false>> {
    typedef F first;
    static const bool second = true;
};

Pair<int, std::true_type> t;
Pair<int, std::false_type> f;
```

or in a more generic way:

```
template <typename F, typename T, T Val>
struct Pair<F, std::integral_constant<T, Val>> {
    typedef F first;
    static const T second = Val;
};

Pair<int, std::integral_constant<int,42>> p;
```